Using WDT to make detect hung code in embedded system, specifically STM32
I'm designing a bare-metal STM32 firmware that must detect hung/lost code and reset. My approach is to have each of the interrupt base processes (basically interrupt-driven code) increment its own global variable as it runs, then in a highest priority 'supervisor' task, check to ensure each global variable is changing. If any one has stopped changing, then allow the WDT to reset the board.
Does this sound like a sound approach? Any better ideas?

In this design, there are no infrequent interrupts, so I don't need to account for those. This is bare-metal, so there are no os resources.

Generally better to simply ask for a solution than to propose your own solution and invite opinion.  You may get several alternatives you have not thought of and can then draw your own opinion.  Discussion of the merits or otherwise of your solution is a probably distraction.

"If any one has stopped changing, then allow the WDT to reset the board." If so then you need no software mechanism for this - you simply need to configure the hardware WDT to an appropriate timeout. The only reason you'd supervise individual tasks from software is if some are considered less critical than others and that the program may be allowed to continue execution despite tasks hanging. Even if "continue execution" just means gracefully closing everything down in a safe manner before doing a MCU reset. Or alternatively in automotive/med-tech, to implement a "limp home mode".

Assuming a foreground/background "super-loop" architecture, with interrupt handlers and a single main thread, then I would suggest a better method would be to implement timeouts for each interrupt.
For example assuming you have implemented a basic system tick interface (using SYSTICK on Cortex-M), with a function tickms() returning elapsed time in milliseconds.  Then for each interrupt being watch-dogged you might have an enumeration such as:
typedef enum
{
    WDG_UART1,
    WDG_UART2,
    WDG_TIMER1,
    ...
    NUMBER_OF_WDG
} eWdg ;

Then an array such as:
volatile struct
{
    unsigned period ;
    unsigned timestamp ;
} wdg[NUMBER_OF_WDG] =
{
    {1000, 0}, // WDG_UART1
    {1000, 0,  // WDG_UART2
    {100,  0}  // WDG_TIMER1
    ...
}

and an API:
void wdgReset( eWdg wdg_id )
{
    wdg[wdg_id].timestamp = tickms() ;
}

void wdgCheck()
{
    for( int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_WDG; i++ )
    {
        while( tickms() - wdg[i].timestamp > wdg[i].period )
        {
            // spin while timeout expired until 
            // interrupt recovers or hardware watchdog
            // fires
        }
       
        resetHwWatchdog() ;
    }
}

Then each interrupt resets its timeout via wdgReset(), and the main loop, continuously checks the software watchdogs thus:
int main()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        // do any background processing here
        backgroundTasks() ;

        // Check interrupts
        wdgCheck()
    }
}

Then:

if the main thread stalls, the hardware watchdog will fire,
if any interrupt stalls, the hardware watchdog will fire,
if an interrupt stops firing, the wdgCheck() will spin and the hardware watchdog will fire,
if everything is working normally, the software watchdogs will be reset, and the hardware watchdog will be serviced by wdgCheck(),
every task or interrupt has its own specific period suited to its expected rate in the application.

Note on Cortex-M you can issue a software reset via the NVIC, so you could optionally reset immediately on a software watchdog expiry rather then wait for the hardware watchdog.
Clearly this is just a pseudocode outline, and purely illustrative - it could be refined and extended in several ways.  If you were to use an RTOS, you could similarly protect tasks, with the supervisor either in the idle loop or in a task having a lower priority than any other.
One refinement I would suggest would be to have a dynamic registry of software watchdogs rather then the static array and have an API:
tWdgHandle wdgCreate( unsigned period ) ;

for example so that tasks and device drivers can independently add their own watchdogs, and wdgCheck() would iterate all registered handlers.  A task could even modify the period dynamically as required (if it were temporarily disabled for example):
void wdgSetPeriod( tWdgHandle wdg, unsigned period ) ;


This is a pretty common design pattern and general good advise (+1), but I wouldn't name this "watchdog" to avoid confusion with the hardware watchdog. The way I usually implement something like this is to kick the physical watchdog at the start of the super loop, then implement a fixed timeout per task using software timers (like Cortex M systick etc) to detect that a task is stuck. From there on break the busy-wait and pass along an error code to the main error handler, which then makes the decision if this is critical enough to merit a hw reset or if some "limp home mode" should be used.

@lundin Indeed; it is a simple outline to be elaborated on.  However, your suggestion may be different enough to warrant a separate answer.  I take your point about naming, I would perhaps qualify it with swWdg... but was going for terseness in the answer.

First of all, please note that if no task is allowed to hang, then the simplest method is just to set the hardware watchdog timer accordingly, given that a blunt MCU reset is an acceptable way of dealing with errors.
You only need software supervision in case:

Upon error, you want to gracefully stop and terminate the program, reporting errors etc before doing a MCU reset, or
Certain tasks are considered less critical even if hanging, or
You are implementing some manner of "limp home" meaning report errors but try to execute the program the best you can even in case of errors (meaning some manner of mission-critical product).

For simplicity lets assume that every task is allowed to consume at most x ms, without individual timeouts. Pseudo code might look like this:
typedef err_t task_t (void);  // function template for tasks


void main (void)
{
  /* init everything here */


  static task_t* const task[] = 
  {
    /* misc tasks in turn calling the drivers */
    uart_task,
    lcd_task,
    buttons_task,
  };

  state_t state = UART_STATE; // in case the list of tasks is also some manner of state machine

  for(;;)
  {
    kick_dog(); // refresh the hardware WDG here, and only here

    err_t result = OK;
    timer_start(n_milliseconds); // some fixed timeout shorter than hw WDG timeout
      do // busy-wait polling
      {
        result = task[state](); // non-blocking call polling something in turn
      } while(!timer_timeout() && result==ERR_BUSY);
    timer_stop();

    // here result is either OK, ERR_BUSY meaning timeout, or some other error code

    state = error_handler(result); // all error handling and state changes in the program here
  }
}

In some systems you'll also have a switch between safe and operational modes and perhaps revert to the safe mode in case of errors.

With respect to cases where supervision is required, in the question, the issue may not be a hung task, but an expected regular interrupt no longer occurring.  For example if some erroneous software disabled an interrupt and does not reenable it in a timely fashion, or a hardware fault, or a misconfiguration causing a slower than expected interrupt rate.

@Clifford With this design, the "non-block calls" would be polling as ISR flag or similar to see if the task is done. Now of course with things like UART, the whole thing is asynchronous so the middle layer will need some intelligence regarding that. Otherwise instead of calling some "timer_stop" we may as well call a function reading the time elapsed to see if it is relevant and as expected.
